# How to add In-App Purchase for ( Consumable ) Run time

Tags: ios, iphone

I am new in iOS development, I want to implement In-App purchase for my application.
The scenario is :

1) Product added by Admin side (Admin Panel) , that why I am not able to register each product separately.

2) For that I have used one iTunes id like "com.company.asss.prod1"  and purchase type "Consumable"

3)Use same Product Identifier for each Product (com.company.asss.prod1)

4) when I  buy first item it will work fine ...

5) when i try to purchase second item , it will call  `[ - (void)productPurchased:(NSNotification *)notification ]` method Two time for First and Second Item.

6) when I try to purchase Third item , it will call (`productPurchased:` ) method three times for First, Second  and third Item.......

Code :

Comment: Please provide some code, I think you are not calling "finishTransaction" function after completing the purchase event.

Answer (score 0):

You should set some integer a boolean value for this also you can use NSString. Now you have to check that if first product is purchased then not to call in app purchase for first product and so on..

Answer (score 0):

Please provide some more details. The info provided is not enough to understand the scenario that you face.
For the proper dynamic implementation of the consumable purchase:

Once transaction is completed, following delegate method of SKPaymentTransactionObserver is called:

-(void)completeTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {

```
NSLog(@"completeTransaction...");

if ([transaction.payment.productIdentifier isEqualToString:@"com.company.asss.prod1"])          

{
// WRITE YOUR PIECE OF CODE HERE
}
```

}